# Message converter not working in spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Hi i am making a web application using spring jpa and hibernate.
In my servlet.xml file i have placed the following lines of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd">


  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
            <beans:property name="objectMapper">
                <beans:ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>   
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.*.controller" />


<util:properties id="portalProperties" location="classpath:portal.abc.properties"></util:properties>
<util:properties id="imageProperties" location="classpath:image.properties"></util:properties>
<tx:annotation-driven />


<task:executor id="asyncExecutor" pool-size="25"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" /> 


<annotation-driven  conversion-service="applicationConversionService" />    

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />



<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
    <beans:map>
      <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </beans:map>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
    <beans:list>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="defaultViews">
    <beans:list>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
        <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
      </beans:bean>
    </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/style.css" location="/style.css" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />

<beans:bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

<beans:bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="converters">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean class="com.abc.util.StringTrimmingConverter"/>
    </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>



<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false"/>
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>     
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In the above file i have mentioned the message converter.But when i call for a POST service request putting some values it gives me

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

My pom.xml code snippet

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>  
            <version>2.1.0</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>  
            <version>2.1.0</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>  
            <version>2.1.0</version>  
        </dependency>
```

I am able to return json but unable to accept json in the request body.
I have kept the

> Content-Type: application/json

in my header while calling for the web service.
Can anyone please help me in understanding why my application is unable to accept the json data.
My controller code snippets

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveTimings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Outlet saveTimings(@RequestBody Timing timing) throws Exception {

    return timing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've registered your Jackson converter to a wrong media type it should be

```
<beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
```

instead, and add `<beans:property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>`

Comment: hi, actually i tried that too, but didn't work, so i tried this one. But this also didn't work. Anyways i have updated my question with the correct type, To avoid any confusion.

Comment: than you're most likely not sending a prefixed json, I've edited an answer, you can either toggle it to false or omit altogether

Comment: Thanx a lot dude, it worked. Now getting different error but its accepting json,that much i can tell.

Comment: :(, My happiness was short lived, I accidentally mapped the same URL to two different implementation,that gave me some weird error .The above issue is still unresolved